# How To Enable Compcache?

Tags: kernel

Compcache is a form of compressed ram swap that should improve performance in some circumstances for memory starved machines.
http://code.google.com/p/compcache/

Apparently Ubuntu has had this available for a bit now, and I attempted to enable it, and found this post:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6609064&postcount=10

What other steps do I have to take to enable compcache on Ubuntu, or is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Ubuntu wiki entry on Compcache](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Compcache), I think that's it. But in another post in the thread you linked to, a user suggests tweaking the setting. Also, as you can see here, there's a way to set an upper limit to the memory used by a temporary file system.

Comment: I can not verify it is working in any way I know, however yes, I found the settings right in initramfs.conf, and set it to use 20% and lzma compression. Thanks for the answer! If I find out more I will share it here, and if it is truly enabled this is the answer. :)

Comment: The compcache page says that it should show up in my list of swaps, it does not. Though the /dev/ramzswap0 file is there I am unable to run sudo swapon with it. I get this error: swapon: /dev/ramzswap0: read swap header failed: Invalid argument

I assume I have to run mkswap on it, but that fails as well. mkswap: error: swap area needs to be at least 40 KiB

Comment: Did some testing, seems like it works even though I am unable to confirm it.

Comment: No, the method was right but due to a bug, I am unable to start it without first running: sudo /usr/lib/initramfs-tools/bin/rzscontrol /dev/ramzswap0 --init && sudo swapon -p 100 /dev/ramzswap0. I added this to the rc.local.

Answer (score 4):

Compcache is deprecated in favor of zRam since Natty. I recommend using [zramwap](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/increased-performance-in-linux-with.html) instead, it has an install-a-package setup process and comes with sane defaults that automatically adapt to your system specs.